# Hide alert dialog in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, show-hide, builder

I have a simple alert dialog, it ll display when a button click is occurs.
and hide automatically after receiving data from web service (On Button click ) .

The code below is showing the alert dialog, but i cant hide it after receiving data also.

```
alertDialog1.setTitle("Please Wait");
                        alertDialog1.setCancelable(false);
                        alertDialog1.setMessage("Fetching Info");
                        alertDialog1.show();`
```

Comment: No My Friend, its not working with me. I have already try that.

Comment: If you do not use a custom view it should dismiss when you click any of the action buttons (PositiveButton,NegativeButton or NeutralButton) you set. But if you use a custom view you should dismiss it on custom button click event

Answer (score 6):

After you receive your data (don't know how/where you are getting the data) call [dismiss()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss())

```
alertDialog1.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
alertdialog1.setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your code snippet?

Comment: dialog will get closed on click of button by default